# Listener for all jface actions similar to IExecutionListener

Tags: eclipse, listener, jface

In eclipse, there is a listener for any [`org.eclipse.core.command`](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-12/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fcommands%2Fpackage-summary.html) that is executed - [`org.eclipse.core.commands.IExecutionListener`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSQ2R2_14.0.0/ExternalAPI/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv_4.6.2.v20161123-1159/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/commands/IExecutionListener.html?view=kc).

Is there such listener for jface action? I know you can add a property change listener to a jface action. But what I am looking for is a listener at framework level where it listens to all actions being executed in the application. It is probably possible to write such a listener, but is anything provided out of the box?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is nothing that does this.

Lots of code in Eclipse calls the `IAction` `run` or `runWithEvent` methods directly without going through any centralised service so it is not possible to do this.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to write such a service for jface actions? I mean is there anything inherent to jface action that prevents from building such one?

Comment: There is no central place that you can hook in to. Actions are often just created with `new Action` and the `run` method called directly. There is no equivalent to the command service which manages all commands.

Comment: Ok. I may need to resort to AspectJ then.